# how to display the annonces of each category?

Tags: php, laravel

i have two table `categories` and `annonces` between them hasMany relationship belongsTo, each `category` has several `annonces`, how to display for each `category` the `annonces` corresponds, in my example it displays all the `annonces`.

**landing-page.blade.php**

```
<div id="simplelastads">
         <h2>Les dernières annonces</h2>
         <div class="contentads">
          @foreach($categories as $category)
          <div class="simpleadsemploi">
          <h3><a href="#" title="Offre emploi">{{ $category->name }}</a></h3>
            @foreach($annonces as $annonce)
               <div class="tab_left">
                 <div class="li-child">
                   <a href="#" title="Technicien">{{ $annonce->titre }}</a>
                   <span>{{ $annonce->ville }}({{ $annonce->hay }})</span>
                 </div>
                 <div class="readmore"><a href="#" title="Voir plus...">Voir plus...</a></div>
               </div>
            @endforeach  
          </div>
          @endforeach
        </div>
      </div>
```

**Annonce.php**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Annonce extends Model
{
    public function category() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Category');
    }

    }
```

**Category.php**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Category extends Model
{
     protected $guarded = [];

    protected $table = 'category';

    public function annonces(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Annonce');
    }

}
```

**LandingPageController.php**

```
 public function index()
    {
        $categories = Category::all();
        $annonces = Annonce::all();
        
        return view('landing-page')->with(
            [
            'categories'=> $categories,
            'annonces'  => $annonces
        ]);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct the controller and the view like this

**landing-page.blade.php**

```html
<div id="simplelastads">
    <h2>Les dernières annonces</h2>
    <div class="contentads">
        @foreach($categories as $category)
            <div class="simpleadsemploi">
                <h3><a href="#" title="Offre emploi">{{ $category->name }}</a></h3>
                @foreach($category->annonces as $annonce)
                   <div class="tab_left">
                     <div class="li-child">
                       <a href="#" title="Technicien">{{ $annonce->titre }}</a>
                       <span>{{ $annonce->ville }}({{ $annonce->hay }})</span>
                     </div>
                     <div class="readmore"><a href="#" title="Voir plus...">Voir plus...</a></div>
                   </div>
                @endforeach  
            </div>
        @endforeach
    </div>
</div>
```

Use the eager loading for the annonces to improve performance `with('annonces')`

**LandingPageController.php**

```php
public function index()
{
    $categories = Category::with('annonces')->get();
            
    return view('landing-page')->with([
        'categories'=> $categories
    ]);
}
```

Comment: thx for answer but he give me this error Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::all()

Comment: You can't use `->all()` after `->with()`; needs to be `->get()`